# Add text after price

Tags: price, tax

I have Magento 1.8.1.0 and I would like to add text just after the price.
Example:

Now I have:
1 764,81 CHF

I would like to have add the text HT example:
1 764,81 CHF **HT**

I've tried to follow this tutorial:http://www.collaboration133.com/add-text-before-price-in-magento-1-8-1/2746/ but it doesn't work. I've tried ET Currency Manager extension, it's work but in the cart description I didn't want it to appear.

note: HT is the abreviation of Excl. Tax in french

Answer (score 2):

Just rewrite the `Mage_Directory_Model_Currency::formatPrecision(...)` and add your text before the `</span>`

**EDIT**

I gave a solution to edit ALL the prices of the website.

If you want to only add suffix/prefix to catalog prices, you have to edit the `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml` template.

There is a lot of case 'cause Magento manage a lot of type of prices.
It depends on your product type, the catalog rules, the special prices, tax settings, etc.

Find your (or yours) type and just edit the DOM.

Comment: Where can I found the `Mage_Directory_Model_Currency::formatPrecision(...)` ?

Comment: In `app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php`. But I recommend you to rewrite the model in your own module instead of editing this file.

Comment: It's work but in the cart it's wrong because I always have my "HT" text.
I just need this "HT" on catalog and product page. Is it possible?

Comment: My bad, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need add this for all prices, you can edit currency symbol in System->Manage Currency->Symbols. 
If you need this in one place - you can get formated price if add this string in place where you need
Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getPrice(), true, false) . " HT"

Answer (score 0):

If you need add this for all prices, in your_path_app/template/catalog/product/price.phtml

```
<div class="price-box">

  // code

  // ad this span before </div>

  <span class="label-ht">HT</span>

</div>
```

you can change the css of span